# Integrating Salesforce Mobile app with Custom hybrid/native mobile app

Tags: salesforce1-app, integration, hybrid

Users use Salesforce to manage opportunities and customers. once opportunity is created in SalesForce we need that opportunity id to be passed to another app not hosted on salesforce and that app takes the business flow further for creating quote, etc..

This app is provided by another vendor that is not built on Salesforce platform/sdk. The server side has exposed REST apis too.

Is there a way to integrate the two apps? any reference / documentation would help.